# Unable to click a href link using Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, href

I have an HTML href link

```
<a class="btn btn-icon-text btn-secondary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#recordSharingDownloadModal" href="/person/mL7CD8tR59g2Cy2/health-record/sharing/media/clinical-summary/%7B7c-06-74-be-dc-67-47-5d-be-92-4c-58-5a-fd-1b-8f%7D/download-options/" title="Download Document">Download</a>
```

using Selenium I need to click the link. Currently, I am using below code -

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(@href='/person/mL7CD8tR59g2Cy2/health-record/sharing/media/clinical-summary/%7B7c-06-74-be-dc-67-47-5d-be-92-4c-58-5a-fd-1b-8f%7D/download-options/')]")).click();
```

But it is throwing an error

> "java.lang.NullPointerException"

I have also tried to click the button using CssSelector but still the same error. I need to click a Download button under clinical summary section but there are multiple sections with the same button name. Only the HREF is unique.

Can anyone please help me?

The piece of code:

```
package LaunchIQHealth;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptExecutor;
import org.openqa.selenium.OutputType;
import org.openqa.selenium.TakesScreenshot;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.*;

public class AutomateIQHealth 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException
    {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Users\\abc\\Desktop\\chromedriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20);
            driver.get("url");
            ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("scroll(0,400)").equals("Clinical Summaries");  
            wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//*[contains(text(), 'Download")));      
            driver.findElements(By.xpath("//a[@href='/person/mL7CD8tR59g2Cy2/health-record/sharing/media/clinical-summary/%7B7c-06-74-be-dc-67-47-5d-be-92-4c-58-5a-fd-1b-8f%7D/download-options/']")).get(0).click();
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: `driver` is probably null. You need to initialize it.

Comment: I think you haven't initiated  the driver first of all. Can you share the complete code that you have tried?

Comment: I have initiated the driver. All other clicks, type etc are working. I am facing issue with the HREF.

Comment: I have added the piece of code. in the description

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I consider your current pasted code as the exact one, you won't be able to do either:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(@href='/person/mL7CD8tR59g2Cy2/health-record/sharing/media/clinical-summary/%7B7c-06-74-be-dc-67-47-5d-be-92-4c-58-5a-fd-1b-8f%7D/download-options/')]")).click();
```

> or

```
driver.findElements(By.xpath("//a[@href='/person/mL7CD8tR59g2Cy2/health-record/sharing/media/clinical-summary/%7B7c-06-74-be-dc-67-47-5d-be-92-4c-58-5a-fd-1b-8f%7D/download-options/']")).get(0).click();
```

The reason is, `chromedriver` happily opens the `Chrome Browser` for you but as you have tried to `executeScript("scroll(0,400)").equals("Clinical Summaries");` **but** as per the [**documentation**](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/JavascriptExecutor.html)  **`JavascriptExecutor`** which is an **`Interface`** and the associated methods **`executeScript`** and **`executeAsyncScript`** can't invoke `click()` method.

Comment: I have the URL loaded and also the button to be clicked is visible on the screen. I am not allowed to share the URL so I didn't put it up

Comment: Actually, I need to scroll down in order to make the Download button visible. Can you please let me know some alternate method for the same?

Comment: @Tiyasa Simply remove the `click()` call, you will be able to scroll down. If my answer have catered to your question Accept the Answer please.

Comment: I am not sure on what you said.I need to scroll down to the section where the download button is available and for that, I have used 

((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("scroll(0,400)").equals("Clinical Summaries");

But after that I need to click on Download button and I have used the following for that:

driver.findElements(By.xpath("//a[@href='/person/mL7CD8tR59g2Cy2/health-record/sharing/media/clinical-summary/%7B7c-06-74-be-dc-67-47-5d-be-92-4c-58-5a-fd-1b-8f%7D/download-options/']")).get(0).click();

Except HREF, there is no other unique value for the button.

Comment: @Tiyasa As I said if you remove the call to `click()` you would be able to get rid of `NPE`. If your requirement have changed feel free to raise a new question as per your new requirement.

Comment: As per my question, I am unable to click on a button with the HREF present, if I remove the click(), how will it click then?

Comment: @Tiyasa Definitely we can't invoke the Java `click()` method inconjunction with the JS call. JS Scroll & Java Click can't be compounded. You have to handle the`click()` later in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried giving the `anchor` an `id` and using `findElement(By.id(IDTag))` ?

An alternative I use is `sendKeys(ENTER)` on the element.

One or the other usually works.

Answer (score -1):

how about,

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@data-target='#recordSharingDownloadModal']")
System.out.println(element) 
element.click();
```

Comment: and what does it prints in step 2??

Comment: Sorry I didn't get you. Which print?

Comment: `System.out.println(element) `